# DB Migration in Spring boot

Tags: java, json, database, spring, spring-boot

I want to load a json file in to Database while application start up.

Let take an example:

i have a json file as below.

### Person.json

```
{
{
"name":"Rahul",
"age":"61"
},
{
"name":"Raj",
"age":"67"
}
}
```

### DB Table : Person

```
name | age
```

I want to store json data in DB. If i add any new object in json file it should be identified and added.

What is the best design for this. Need to use Spring Boot, Spring.

Comment: "load a json file in to Database while application start up", this concept is known as bootstrapping. you may search this on stackoverflow .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CommandLineRunner and reflect over all the classes inside of your model package and look for a .json file. If you find one, deserialize the contents and save them to a database.

See this link: 
http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2017/07/05/read-json-data-spring-boot-write-database

The code to get all classes within a package can be found here: 
https://dzone.com/articles/get-all-classes-within-package